# My big commerce create cart API call fails since my product option is not assigned a value. How can i assign it a value?

Tags: cart, bigcommerce

### My big commerce product detail

- My product has an id of 149 (*product_id* = 149)
- My product has an assigned option called **sized** (*option_id* =  72) which is a text field.
- My product has *variant_id* of 160 (assumed from the value of *base_variant_id*)

### Add to cart

I call **/api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{$$.env.store_hash}/v3/carts** with the following body

```
    {
      "line_items": [
        {
          "quantity": 5,
          "product_id": 149,
          "variant_id": 160,
           "option_selections": [
            {
              "option_id": 72,
              "option_value": "test"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

### Response if I don't variant Id

The *variant_id* value is my product *base_variant_id*. I needed to add the variant_id otherwise the api call responds with

```
  "errors": {
    "variant": "This product has options, variant ID is required"
  },
  "status": 422,
  "title": "Missing or incorrect required fields",
  "type": "https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/api-status-codes"
}
```

Adding the variant_id got rid of the above error

### Response with variant, but fails due to size option not set

When I make the POST api call, to add to the card, it complains that the **sized** option isn't set

```
{
  "detail": "Please enter some text for the sized option.",
  "status": 422,
  "title": "Missing or incomplete product variant attributes",
  "type": "https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/api-status-codes"
}
```

How do I set the **sized** options value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of “Options” in BigCommerce - one of them is called “Customizations”, the other is called “Variations”.

The difference between the two is that Variations will split your main product down into several “Variants” - these are essentially entirely different iterations of your main product - imagine the same shirt that is made out of cotton vs wool. When you build out a variation, BigCommerce will auto-generate entirely new Variant objects with unique SKU as variant children of the top level product. (If you have a newer store on the V3 products API.)

Customizations, however, do not generate new variants. Consider a silver ring with an option for an engraving - the engraving would not require a brand new “product child type” to be created in the system, it would simply be something that the store owner would customize each time the silver ring was ordered with that option - the base product is the same

You will want to inspect your product in the V3 API with the query string added to the request to expose variants. Instead of using the base_variant_id of the top level product, use the id of the variants that BC has auto-generated for your product.

Alternatively, to see what the variant ID for that option is on the front-end, console log out response.data of the productAttributesChanged function in product-details.js when you select that option you set on the product page itself - BC will return a response object with the variant ID as well

Comment: thanks for the info. i now understand that that my product option is a customization and not a variant ( so I don't need the variant id ). l also noted that when I requested modifiers on my product the id wasn't 72. Once I used the correct  option_id the call to the add cart worked! One last question, how do i return my modifier value when requesting my cart details?  When I  make the GET cart call my modifier option value isn't returned (from your engraving analogy, I cant see the engraving I made)

Comment: @Nick You're using the V3, server-to-server API, is that correct? Or are you using the storefront API? If you're using the V3/carts/{cardid} endpoint, you'll need to include a query parameter to the GET request to include your cart's line item options. You can check out the "Request Parameters" section on the docs: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/cart-checkout/server-server-cart-api/cart/getacart   

You'll likely want `?include=line_items.physical_items.options`

Comment: Mikhail, yes I'm using the  V3, server-to-server API. I followed your instructions and my modifier was returned in my GET cart JSON playload! Thanks for all your help